# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 4

Tags: java, string, indexoutofboundsexception

i need to solve a crossword puzzle and one method is to put a word in the puzzle.
[...]

Ok, I changed my code with the help of your answers now.
Now it's this:

```
public static char[][] setWord(int[] gridSpecEntry, String wordsSpecEntry,
        char[][] grid) {
        if (wordsSpecEntry.length()>0&&wordsSpecEntry.length()==gridSpecEntry[2])
        {
        int y = gridSpecEntry[0];
        int x = gridSpecEntry[1];
        int w = gridSpecEntry[2];
        int r = gridSpecEntry[3];
        if (r == 0) {
            for (int b = 0; b < wordsSpecEntry.length(); b++) {
                grid[y][x + b] = wordsSpecEntry.charAt(b);//line 224
            }
        } else {
            for (int a = 0; a < wordsSpecEntry.length(); a++) {
                grid[y + a][x] = wordsSpecEntry.charAt(a);
            }
        }
    }
    return grid;
}
```

but now i get the following error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 18
at CrosswordPuzzleSolver.setWord(CrosswordPuzzleSolver.java:224)
```

could you help me again please?

Comment: If you are using Eclipse, See: [Eclipse Debugging](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html) or for Netbeans See: [Netbeans Debugging](https://netbeans.org/features/java/debugger.html)

Comment: Please don't change the question after people start answering.  Stack Overflow is supposed to be a repository of questions and answers.  It becomes ridiculous if the answers don't match the questions, because the question changed.  If you have a new question, please ask a new question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `w` is larger than the length of your String. Consider doing this instead:

```
int w = wordsSpecEntry.length();       //length of the word
```

Answer (score 0):

This parameter is not correct if you get this error:

```
    int w = gridSpecEntry[2];       //length of the word
```

Or if it's not length of the `wordsSpecEntry` just add another validation:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < w && i < wordsSpecEntry.length(); i++)               {
```